# How can I create a partial year dummy variable for a panel dataset?

Tags: panel-data, categorical-encoding

This might be a dumb question, but here goes.

I have a panel dataset that includes annual firm-level data from 2010-2020. I am interested in the effect of a specific policy change (X) in my outcome variable (Y). The policy is in effect from 1/1/2017 to 3/31/2019. Therefore the policy is in effect for all 12 months of 2017, all 12 months of 2018, but only 3 months of 2019. How can I create a dummy variable to properly capture this given that my firm-level data is measured annually?

If I make X be a dummy variable equal to one for 2017, 2018, and 2019 observations, this would improperly treat all 12 months of 2019 as being affected by the policy change (when in reality only 3 months are affected).

Comment: You could have separate indicators (dummy variables) for being 2017, 2018, 2019.  The effect in 2018 might well be different from that in 2017 just as the effect in 2019 could be different from that in previous years.

Comment: Or assign 0.25 to the variable for 2019? Clearly not ideal, but a solution.